# How to start 64-bit programming with visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit

What do I need to do to start making 64bit programs in VS?
 I tried using 64bit solution platform setting and used "copy settings from x86" option. The process shows up as 64bit. Is there anything else? Am I missing some interesting options?

Comment: It's a bit obvious, but you need a 64-bit platform to run the resulting application on.  You can build the 64-bit app on a 32-bit box, but you can't run it there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope. All you need to do is set to build an x64 target, which you already did.